# reactjs remember me functionality on localstorage

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a problem here when creating a remember me function in Reactjs.

So, I managed to enter the username, password and isChecked into localstorage.

However, when I logged out, all the data in the local storage was deleted including the username, password and isChecked.

***How do you make the username, password and isChecked persist after logging out? Thank You***

MyCode =

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    import Logo from "../../../../assets/images/logo.png";
    import BackgroundProfile from "../../../../assets/images/background-profile.png";
    import { VscKey } from "react-icons/vsc";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import { signin } from "../../../../service/account";
    import { toast } from "react-toastify";
    
    export default function CardLogin(props) {
      const {
        labelText,
        inputText,
        loginType,
        firstOptionLogin,
        secondOptionLogin,
        labelIcon,
        firstRoute,
        secondRoute,
        firstIcon,
        secondIcon,
      } = props;
    
      const [username, setUsername] = useState(() =>
        localStorage.checkbox ? localStorage.username : ""
      );
      const [password, setPassword] = useState(() =>
        localStorage.checkbox ? localStorage.password : ""
      );
      const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(() => !!localStorage.checkbox);
      const initialValue = {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        nik: "",
      };
    
      const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    
      const handleSubmit = () => {
        if (isChecked && username !== "") {
          localStorage.username = username;
          localStorage.password = password;
          localStorage.checkbox = isChecked ? "1" : "";
        }
    
        const data = new URLSearchParams();
        console.log(loginType);
        if (loginType === "username") {
          data.append("username", initialValue.username);
          data.append("password", initialValue.password);
          data.append("grant_type", "password");
        }
    
        setIsLoading(true);
        signin(data, loginType)
          .then((response) => {
            if (response?.code === 200) {
              console.log(response);
              localStorage.setItem(
                "accessToken",
                JSON.stringify(response.data.accessToken)
              );
              localStorage.setItem(
                "userSession",
                JSON.stringify(response.data.accessTokenExpiresAt)
              );
              window.location.reload();
            } else {
              toast.error(response.message);
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          })
          .finally(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
          });
      };
    
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundSize: "100% 75%",
            backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
            height: "100%",
            backgroundImage: `url(${BackgroundProfile})`,
          }}
        >
          {/* Button Back on The Top of Page */}
          <button>
            <div className="rounded-full w-5 md:w-10 h-5 md:h-10 p-3 relative top-2 left-2">
              {/* <FaArrowLeft className="text-[#DD2729] text-xs md:text-base absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-1/2" /> */}
            </div>
          </button>
    
          {/* Logo & Card Login */}
          <img
            src={Logo}
            className="absolute top-6 bottom-6 right-4  w-2/5 md:w-1/5"
            alt="Logo"
          />
          <div className="mx-auto mt-8 w-3/5 md:w-2/5 bg-white px-5 py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-md drop-shadow-xl">
            <button>
              {/* <FaArrowLeft className="text-[#DD2729] text-xs md:text-base" /> */}
            </button>
            <article
              style={{ fontFamily: "ubuntu" }}
              className="text-center text-[#808285] text-xs md:text-lg"
            >
              Selamat Datang! <br /> Silakan masuk untuk mulai menggunakan aplikasi
            </article>
    
            {/* Form Login*/}
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="pt-3 md:pt-5">
              <div>
                <label
                  htmlFor={loginType}
                  className="text-[#424242] text-xs md:text-sm "
                >
                  {labelText}
                </label>
                <div className="flex">
                  <div
                    className={`w-10 flex items-center justify-center bg-blue-lighter border-y border-l border-[#9E9E9E] rounded-l text-blue-dark`}
                  >
                    {labelIcon}
                  </div>
                  <input
                    id="username"
                    name="username"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={inputText}
                    value={username}
                    onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                    className={`w-full border-l-0 border-[#9E9E9E] rounded-r text-xs md:text-lg font-sans`}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="pt-2 md:pt-3">
                <label
                  htmlFor="password"
                  className="text-[#424242] text-xs md:text-sm"
                >
                  Password
                </label>
                <div className="flex">
                  <div
                    className={`w-10 flex items-center justify-center bg-blue-lighter border-y border-l border-[#9E9E9E] rounded-l text-blue-dark `}
                  >
                    <VscKey className="text-[#A8A8A8] text-xl" />
                  </div>
                  <input
                    id="password"
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Masukkan kata sandi anda"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    className={`w-full border-l-0 border-[#9E9E9E] rounded-r text-xs md:text-lg font-normal `}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              {/* End of Form Login */}
    
              {/* Remember me & Forgot Password */}
              <div className="flex pt-3 items-center justify-between">
                <div className="flex items-center gap-1.5">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={isChecked}
                    name="lsRememberMe"
                    onChange={(e) => setIsChecked(e.target.checked)}
                    className="rounded"
                  />
                  <label htmlFor="" className="text-xs md:text-sm">
                    Remember me
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="">
                  <Link
                    to="/forgot-password"
                    className="text-xs md:text-sm underline underline-offset-1 font-bold"
                  >
                    Forgot password
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
    
              <input
                type="submit"
                value={isLoading ? "Loading" : "Masuk"}
                disabled={isLoading}
                className="bg-[#EA001E] hover:bg-[#F55151] active:bg-[#BA0D0D] w-full text-white font-bold text-md rounded-lg p-2 mt-4 shadow-xl cursor-pointer text-xs md:text-sm"
              />
            </form>
            {/* End of Remember me & Forgot Password */}
    
            {/* Login Option */}
            <div className="mt-3">
              <h4 className="login-selection text-center text-xs md:text-sm">
                or login with
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center gap-2 mt-4">
              <Link to={firstRoute}>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-around gap-2 bg-white shadow-xl rounded-full  py-2 px-3 md:px-8">
                  <img
                    src={firstIcon}
                    alt="Login Icons"
                    className="w-2/6 md:w-4/5"
                  />
                  <div className="font-bold text-xs md:text-sm uppercase">
                    {firstOptionLogin}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Link>
              <Link to={secondRoute}>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-around gap-2 bg-white shadow-xl rounded-full  py-2 px-3 md:px-10">
                  <img
                    src={secondIcon}
                    alt="Login Icons"
                    className="w-2/6 md:w-4/5"
                  />
                  <div className="font-bold text-xs md:text-sm uppercase">
                    {secondOptionLogin}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Link>
            </div>
            {/* End of Login Option */}
    
            {/* Alternative Register */}
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center gap-2 mt-4 text-xs md:text-sm">
              <p>Don't have an account?</p>
              <Link
                to="/signup"
                className="text-[#DE1B1B] font-bold text-xs md:text-sm"
              >
                Sign Up
              </Link>
            </div>
            {/* End of Alternative Register */}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it’s being deleted?

Comment: I checked it in inspect

Answer (score -1):

CASE CLOSED, in the form section onSubmit={handleSubmit} I delete it to just form, then onSubmit={handleSubmit} I move it to button to become onClick={handleSubmit}.

thank you for answering my question. i appreciate it